# Getting data from firebase but not showing in recyclerview

Tags: android

I am new in android development. I am trying to create list of firebase data. so i have created a recyclerview and represent the data in recyclerview.
I have featched data from firebase and assign to adapter class. but data is not showing in recyclerview.

Fragment Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
DatabaseReference reference;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Carmodel> list = new ArrayList<>();;
CarAdapter adapter;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AddCar");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Carmodel p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Carmodel.class);
                Log.e("Get Data", p.getCarName());
                list.add(p);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    adapter = new CarAdapter(getContext(), list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return root;
}
}
```

Adapert Class

```
public class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Carmodel> profiles;
public CarAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<Carmodel> p)
{
    context = c;
    profiles = p;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_home, parent, false));
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(profiles.get(position).getCarName());
    holder.seater.setText(profiles.get(position).getSeater());
    holder.price.setText(profiles.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.status.setText(profiles.get(position).getAvailable());
    Picasso.get().load(profiles.get(position).getImageURL()).into(holder.car_image);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return profiles.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name,seater,price, status;
    ImageView car_image;
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CarName);
        seater = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Seater);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Seater);
        car_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are notifying your adapter in wrong time for data change

```
adapter = new CarAdapter(getContext(), list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Carmodel p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Carmodel.class);
            Log.e("Get Data", p.getCarName());
            list.add(p);
        }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Please modify your method like this

Comment: Can you fetch data from firebase? Your add value event listener called ?

Comment: You can have problem with your model layout. You can log OnBindViewHolder and OnCreate ViewHolder to detect the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Carmodel p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Carmodel.class);
```

make you sure it is (p) not empty

Comment: Log.e("Get Data", p.getCarName()); this line is showing printing data.

Comment: check it adapter Context and Model p on Recycler Adapter class via breakpoint to make sure it isn't empty